# Why are bigger sample sizes important?

Tags: probability, statistics

It is common to hear about the sample size of some experiment, but why is it important? I mean, suppose we are investigating some process which can output $6$ numbers: $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and suppose we obtained the following sequence of digits:

$$2 3 5 2 2 5 1 3 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 5 5 4 6 2 5 3 6$$

Now we could assume that we *have some information* about the process being measured, but all the next digits of this sequence could be $1$, that is:

$$2 3 5 2 2 5 1 3 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 5 5 4 6 2 5 3 61111111111111111111111111111111111\dots$$

Wouldn't this completely change the *information* we had before? If we started measuring the process here:

$$[2 3 5 2 2 5 1 3 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 5 5 4 6 2 5 3 6]1111111111111111111111111111111111\dots$$

We would know something about the set of outputs, but if we started measuring here:

$$2 3 5 2 2 5 1 3 2 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 1 5 5 4 6 2 5 3 6[1111111111111111111111111111111111]\dots$$

Wouldn't we would obtain a completely different knowledge of the set of outputs? Now, suppose someone argue that the sample size was too small and we take a bigger sample size, then the same problem could occur. If we append the belief that the sequence generated behaves like a fair dice (or any other weighted dice), I guess we can have a better knowledge of the possible numerical outcomes. But suppose we are investigating a process in nature, can we mathematically prove that a sequence of numbers behaves like a fair dice or any other weighted dice or that comes from belief?

> With *information* I mean any statistical relationships between the numbers in the set of outputs: Average, variance, etc. Which I suppose are "statistical information".

Comment: Even if your process is not behaving like a sequence of fair dice, it is only by gathering enough data that you will be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible that if we were to increase our sample size, the increased sample is actually less representative than the original smaller sample, but that is *less likely* to happen than the other way around. That is, we could also start with a small sample:

11111111111

but then when we take a larger sample, we find:

1111111111124352634143525635142

In general, a larger sample size is *more likely* to be representative of the target than a smaller sample size, so a larger sample size is, on average, better.

Answer (score 1):

In short, probability theory allows to evaluate *the probability* that a given sequence is indeed random, and a battery of tests is available for that purpose.

But nothing can *prove* that it is indeed random (unless you have a detailed knowledge of the sequence generation process).

By the way, the pseudo-random number generators will pass most of the probabilistic tests (they are designed for that purpose), but they are completely deterministic !

Answer (score 1):

Most statistical inference begins with the assumption that the data
are randomly sampled from a particular distribution. For example,
we may have $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} 
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma = 10).$

In that case a 95% confidence interval (CI) for $\mu$ is of the form
$\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$ where $M = 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$
is called the margin of error. Obviously, $M$ decreases as the sample size $n$
increases. Specifically, increasing $n$ by a factor of 4 will cut $M$ in half. If $M$ is too large, then the CI may be useless for practical
purposes.

After the data are collected and the CI is computed, one may run various
tests to see if assumptions are met. For example, a test to see if the data
are consistent with sampling from a normal population, a test to see if
$\sigma = 10$ is a reasonable population standard deviation, and a test to see if the data seem random (perhaps checking for particular nonrandom
patterns in the data).

Answer (score 0):

The key term is the sampling distribution. If sampled once (randomly), true, it may not be representative of the population. However, if sampled many times, it will be. Consequntly in sampling, the sample size is crucial as sampling by $2$ or sampling by $10$ or $30$ makes a significant difference.